# Randomizing a movie title based on a movie genre

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I am trying to create two buttons, one is to select a genre that you want to watch which I have shown below. The second one is to randomize a title based on the genre chosen. But I am a little lost on how I would take the value of the chosenMovieGenre function into another function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
     let changedGenre = document.getElementById('dropdown-movie').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        
            fetch("https://movies-tvshows-data-imdb.p.rapidapi.com/?type=get_random-movies&page=1")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(function chosenMovieGenre(jsonObject) {
                let arrayGenres = jsonObject.movie_results
                arrayGenres.forEach((title) => {
                    let genreChosen = event.target.value
                    if (title.genres[0] === genreChosen){
                        // console.log(title.title)
                        return title.title 
                    }
                }) 
            })
        
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    
    })
```

Comment: I already have the algorithm on how to randomize the titles I just dont know how to take the genre chosen from the user and randomize those values

Comment: Where do you want to use that other function? In the same promise chain or somewhere else? If its in the same chain just add another .then((chosenMovieGenre) => { //do your thing})

Comment: @RaniSharim Okay, how would I put the value of chosenMovieGenre into that function? its out of that functions scope?

Comment: Thats how promise chains work. If you return a value from a promise its automatically passed to the next promise on the chain. So return title.title  will be passed as chosenMovieGenre.

Comment: @RaniSharim Ahhhh! That's perfect, thank you so much. I will try that out now!